# Android Studio MACOS "No target device found."

Tags: android, android-studio, macos

al intentar ejecutar una aplicación tan básica como HolaMundo, me salta este error:

**body { font-family: .AppleSystemUIFont; font-size: 13;} ul li {list-style-type:circle;}No target device found.**

Alguien me puede ayudar a solucionarlo, estoy desde un MacBook.

He estado mirando por internet pero no he encontrado cosas al respecto.

Comment: Añado Información: Cuando creo un proyecto de 0 y le doy a ejecutar directamente me sale el mismo error. No creo que sea de que algo este mal programado.

Comment: Estas tratando de subir la aplicación de android studio a tu dispositivo? antes lo pudiste realizar sin problema? tienes el "modo desarrollador" configurado

Comment: Acabo de terminar de instalar Android Studio y es la primera aplicación que hago, siguiendo un tutorial de internet. De todas maneras he vuelto a buscarle problema por internet y están apareciendo otros casos como el mío. Debe de ser un fallo de la propia actualización o algo. Porque todos los casos abiertos son de hace menos de 24horas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución al final ha sido bastante simple.

Cuando sale ese error tienes que crear un nuevo dispositivo virtual clicando al lado de ejecutar código. Una vez allí le das a "AVD MANAGER" y seleccionar crear nuevo dispositivo virtual.

Una vez creado al ejecutar el código se te abrirá un emulador con el dispositivo y tu aplicación.

POR SI ACASO AÑADO ESTO: en Mac no viene instalado por defecto el paquete de emulador. para instalarlo tendremos que ir al menú tools, luego a ANDROID SDK y luego en el menú de la ventana que se nos abre ir a SDK TOOLS y descargamos la opción de ANDROID EMULADOR y ANDROID AUTO DESKTOP HEAD UNIT EMULATOR.